# TSQL - Have seperate queries show data side by side?

Tags: t-sql

Kind of an odd request, but is it possible to have seperate TSQL Queries show data side by side without using an outer join? I'm wondering if I'm completely complicating this...

Here's what I'm looking to do:

I have 12 queries that will give me a count of records and I'd like them, instead of being stacked on top of each other, to show the records from right to left as if they're in a table.

So from these queries:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS 'INTERNET JAN 12'
  FROM dbo.CONTACT AS AA
  JOIN dbo.Document AS BB
  ON AA.ACCOUNTNO = BB.ACCOUNTNO
 WHERE SOURCE IN ('INTERNET', 'EBAY', 'MSN', 'BING', 'GOOGLE', 'YAHOO')
   AND KEY1 = 'EA'
   AND MONTH(BB.Date) = 1
   AND  YEAR(BB.Date) = 2012

SELECT COUNT(*) AS 'INTERNET FEB 12'
  FROM dbo.CONTACT AS AA
  JOIN dbo.Document AS BB
  ON AA.ACCOUNTNO = BB.ACCOUNTNO
 WHERE SOURCE IN ('INTERNET', 'EBAY', 'MSN', 'BING', 'GOOGLE', 'YAHOO')
   AND KEY1 = 'EA'
   AND MONTH(BB.Date) = 2
   AND  YEAR(BB.Date) = 2012

 ...

SELECT COUNT(*) AS 'INTERNET DEC 12'
  FROM dbo.CONTACT AS AA
  JOIN dbo.Document AS BB
  ON AA.ACCOUNTNO = BB.ACCOUNTNO
 WHERE SOURCE IN ('INTERNET', 'EBAY', 'MSN', 'BING', 'GOOGLE', 'YAHOO')
   AND KEY1 = 'EA'
   AND MONTH(BB.Date) = 12
   AND  YEAR(BB.Date) = 2012
```

I want the result set to look like this:

```
 INTERNET JAN 12     INTERNET FEB 12     ...     INTERNET DEC 12
 12                  25                          31
```

Instead of like this:

```
 INTERNET JAN 12
 12

 INTERNET FEB 12
 25

 ...

 INTERNET DEC 12
 31
```

Is this possible without adding in another field and doing an outer join? The end result is to have this in an Excel spreadsheet as a query for an end user to auto update.

Comment: Assuming MSSQL - you should do away with the multiple queries althogether and use PIVOT()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using a temp table as an intermediate resultset to create data you can SUM on ? If your flavor of TSQL is recent and from Microsoft, the CTE will do it:

```
;
WITH temp (Jan12, Feb12, /* ... */ ) AS (
SELECT 
    -- Jan 12
    CASE MONTH(BB.Date)
        WHEN 1 THEN 1 
        ELSE 0 
    END,
    -- Feb 12
    CASE MONTH(BB.Date)
        WHEN 2 THEN 1 
        ELSE 0 
    END
  FROM dbo.CONTACT AS AA
  JOIN dbo.Document AS BB
  ON AA.ACCOUNTNO = BB.ACCOUNTNO
 WHERE SOURCE IN ('INTERNET', 'EBAY', 'MSN', 'BING', 'GOOGLE', 'YAHOO')
   AND KEY1 = 'EA'
   AND  YEAR(BB.Date) = 2012 
)
SELECT SUM(Jan12) AS [Internet Jan 12], SUM(Feb12) AS [Internet Feb 12] -- ... and so on
```

That being said, your case is probably better suited for `PIVOT` - I can't make a reasonable sample without having your database to query in; but it should be easy to figure out [from the documentation.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms177410%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx)

Comment: This worked wonderfully. I'm no stranger to SQL but am still slowly learning TSQL and SQL Server. I appreciate the help!

Comment: One last question...is it possible to union this to another similar query? I continue to get an error when trying to use UNION ALL